# Считывание информации с сайта

Tags: python, парсер

Кто-нибудь вообще знает,как в реальном времени можно считывать какую-либо меняющуюся информацию с сайта в txt.И как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Гугл знает, конечно. Первая ссылка по запросу «python скачать с сайта» https://bdseo.ru/kak-skachat-fajl-na-python-3

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, это называется парсинг сайта. В гугле очень много инфы по этому.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> как в реальном времени можно считывать какую-либо меняющуюся
>   информацию с сайта ?

Непонятно, что Вы имеете в виду под словом "информация" ?

Если Вас интересует содержимое HTML страничек, то есть модуль *Beautiful Soup* (http://wiki.python.su/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/BeautifulSoup)  И читайте странички сколько угодно.

Если же Вас интересует доступ у данным, предоставляемый тем или иным интерент-сервисом, то тут у каждого - свой API. Доступ к погодным данным на яндексе будет работать иначе, чем доступ к погодным данным на гугле.

Ну и аналогично, для разных фотохостингов, чатрумов и т.д. Хозяин сервиса, который предоставляет доступ к неоторым данным, как правило, публикует API такого доступа.